# Django: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'new_patient'

Tags: python, django

When I load a page in my site, I am getting an error for another view function that is not for the current page that I am on. My views look like:

`views.py:`

```
@login_required
def show_patient(request, patient_id):
    print patient_id  #this prints new_patient in terminal
    try:
        patient = Patients.objects.get(user__pk=patient_id)
    except Patients.DoesNotExist:
        error = True
        return render(request, 'patient_notexist.html', {'error': perror})

    else:
        return render(request, 'patient-overview.html', {'patient': patient})

@login_required
def new_patient(request):
    ...
    code to register new patient who will also be a registered user
    ...
```

The show_patient function gets the patient id from the url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dash/$', patientTracker.views.home),
    url(r'^(?P<patient_id>\w+)/$', patientTracker.views.show_patient),
    url(r'^new_patient/$', patientTracker.views.new_patient),
)
```

`models.py`:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE = (('doc', 'Doctor'), ('pat', 'Patient'))
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=254, choices=USER_TYPE)

class Doctors(models.Model):
    practice = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, related_name='doctor')


class Patients(models.Model):   #Abstract User
    dob = models.DateField()
    condition = models.ForeignKey(Condition, blank=True, null=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctors, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, related_name='patient')
```

When I render the new_patient page, I get an error from the show_patient function:
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'new_patient'`

I don't get a traceback from the terminal, just from the testserver debug page. It shows this line as the offending problem:

`patient = Patients.objects.get(user__pk=patient_id)`

Since my models are kind of confusing, what do I need to add to this line to get it working?

The weird part is, I don't even have any patients in my database because whenever I try to add them, I get an error from the show_patient function.

UPDATE:
urls.py of other app in my project

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^accounts/login', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^patient/', include('patientTracker.urls')),
    url(r'^about/', views.home),
    url(r'^accounts/', CustomRegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationForm)),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

After changing the order of my urls.py to:

```
url(r'^dash/$', patientTracker.views.home),
url(r'^new_patient/$', patientTracker.views.new_patient), #switched from below
url(r'^(?P<patient_id>\w+)/$', patientTracker.views.show_patient),
```

I now get the page rendered to `accounts/login` of my base urls.py

Comment: What does the rest of your url.conf look like, and what URL are you using to try to render the new_patient page? That's where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regexp for `show_patient` is too broad, and is listed before your `new_patient` url pattern. Django uses the first matching URL pattern, and `http://127.0.0.1/new_patient/` is matched by `r'^(?P<patient_id>\w+)/$'`. You can either list all your non-show patterns first, or (my recommendation) put something more distinctive in the show patient pattern, eg `^show/(?P<patient_id>\w+)/$`.

Comment: Ok I am in the middle of another non-related error right now, as soon as I finish that, I will get back to you and mark as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I changed the url, but now the url redirects to another app in my django project. I am updating my answer with the urls.py of my other app.

Comment: Your `new_patient` view is declared as requiring login. If you're not logged in when you try to hit the page, redirecting to the login view is the correct behavior.